# How to display Hourly data based on Current Time?

Tags: javascript

I have two values, one from Hourly data and other from Current Time, where its hour is to be compared and display when found match or equal
See below code for better understanding

```
export class HourlyForecast extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};  
    }
    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;       

        if(!data) return null; 
        const time = data.datetime
        const time2 = time.slice(11,13)
        console.log('HOURLY DATA', time2)

        const time5  = moment.tz(this.props.timezone).format('HH:mm').slice(0,2)
        console.log('TIME CURRENT', time5);
}
}

export default HourlyForecast
```

I want to compare the hour value from hourly data with current time's hour value. How to do it?
[image]
See the above image for reference. The Hourly data ranges from 00 to 09 whereas Current Time is 02. The Hourly data must display from 02 comparing with Current Time.

Comment: Unclear - please explain your precise requirements.

Comment: This is not clear at all. Is the information coming from same API or there are multiple apis?

Comment: @seesharper hourly data I get is from api and I want to show the data ranging from 02 since the current time is 02 AM

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja Hourly data I recieve is through api and I want to display the same data ranging from 02 since current time is 02. 00, 01, 02, 03 are hourly intervals that has weather information.

Comment: It'd be helpful to give an example of DATA: not exhaustive, include examples of props you do and don't expect to be rendered. This question isn't so much about React as it is parsing times and JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear though you can try this to compare.

```
async function1(){
    let hourData = await hourlyfunction()
    let currentData await currentTimefunction()
    return hourData==currentData
}
```

Comment: Hi stchr, please see above comments